# Fill graph area with a gradient in HighChart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts and react-highcharts to display some graph in my application. Ideally I would like to color the area of the graph with some gradient, from the documentation and [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/line-time-series) example the option that I should add is this:

```
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: {
                            x1: 0,
                            y1: 0,
                            x2: 0,
                            y2: 1
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
```

I'm trying to replicate the same with the configuration of my graph but it doesn't work, the graph looks exactly the same as if there was no `fillColor` option added. Here's the config of my graph:

```
{
    "title": {
        "text": ""
    },
    "chart": {
        "height": 500,
        "animation": false,
        "events": {}
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": true,
        "align": "center",
        "verticalAlign": "bottom",
        "useHTML": true,
        "y": 15
    },
    "navigator": {
        "enabled": true,
        "adaptToUpdatedData": false,
        "handles": {
            "enabled": false
        },
        "outlineWidth": 0,
        "maskFill": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
        "series": {
            "type": "areaspline",
            "color": "#4572A7",
            "fillOpacity": 0.05,
            "dataGrouping": {
                "smoothed": true
            },
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "marker": {
                "enabled": false
            },
            "data": [
                [
                    1623200400000,
                    1.3675397235722446
                ],
                [
                    1623286800000,
                    1.3482760115327748
                ],
                [
                    1623373200000,
                    1.3546129384275694
                ],
                [
                    1623632400000,
                    1.3414434698775963
                ],
                [
                    1623718800000,
                    1.3312870572603575
                ],
                [
                    1623200400000,
                    1.3675397235722446
                ],
                [
                    1623286800000,
                    1.3482760115327748
                ],
                [
                    1623373200000,
                    1.3546129384275694
                ],
                [
                    1623632400000,
                    1.3414434698775963
                ],
                [
                    1623718800000,
                    1.3312870572603575
                ]
            ]
        },
        "max": null
    },
    "rangeSelector": {
        "enabled": true,
        "inputEnabled": true,
        "buttons": [
            {
                "type": "mtd",
                "count": 1,
                "text": "MTD"
            },
            {
                "type": "ytd",
                "text": "YTD"
            },
            {
                "type": "month",
                "count": 1,
                "text": "1m",
                "preventDefault": true,
                "performancePeriod": "one_month"
            },
            {
                "type": "month",
                "count": 3,
                "text": "3m",
                "preventDefault": true,
                "performancePeriod": "three_months_actual"
            },
            {
                "type": "month",
                "count": 6,
                "text": "6m",
                "preventDefault": true,
                "performancePeriod": "six_months_actual"
            },
            {
                "type": "year",
                "count": 1,
                "text": "1y",
                "preventDefault": true,
                "performancePeriod": "one_year_actual"
            },
            {
                "type": "year",
                "count": 3,
                "text": "3y",
                "preventDefault": true,
                "performancePeriod": "one_year_actual"
            },
            {
                "type": "all",
                "text": "All"
            }
        ],
        "selected": 5
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "labels": {
            "style": {
                "color": false,
                "fontSize": false
            }
        },
        "plotLines": [
            {
                "value": 0,
                "width": 2,
                "color": "silver"
            }
        ]
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "type": "datetime",
        "startOnTick": false,
        "labels": {
            "style": {
                "color": false,
                "fontSize": false
            }
        },
        "max": null,
        "events": {}
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "area": {
            "fillColor": {
                "linearGradient": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    300
                ],
                "stops": [
                    [
                        0,
                        "#333"
                    ],
                    [
                        1,
                        "#444"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        "series": {
            "marker": {
                "lineColor": "white",
                "fillColor": "#203A4C",
                "symbol": "diamond",
                "radius": 3,
                "states": {
                    "hover": {
                        "fillColor": "white",
                        "radius": 5
                    }
                }
            },
            "compare": "percent",
            "compareBase": 0
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "crosshairs": true,
        "dateTimeLabelFormats": {
            "millisecond": "%b %e, %Y",
            "second": "%b %e, %Y",
            "minute": "%b %e, %Y",
            "hour": "%b %e, %Y",
            "day": "%b %e, %Y",
            "week": "%b %e, %Y",
            "month": "%b %e, %Y",
            "year": "%b %e, %Y"
        },
        "headerFormat": "<strong>{point.key}<strong><br/>",
        "split": true,
        "valueDecimals": 2
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "id": null,
            "name": "test",
            "data": [
                [
                    1623200400000,
                    1.3675397235722446
                ],
                [
                    1623286800000,
                    1.3482760115327748
                ],
                [
                    1623373200000,
                    1.3546129384275694
                ],
                [
                    1623632400000,
                    1.3414434698775963
                ],
                [
                    1623718800000,
                    1.3312870572603575
                ],
                [
                    1623200400000,
                    1.3675397235722446
                ],
                [
                    1623286800000,
                    1.3482760115327748
                ],
                [
                    1623373200000,
                    1.3546129384275694
                ],
                [
                    1623632400000,
                    1.3414434698775963
                ],
                [
                    1623718800000,
                    1.3312870572603575
                ]
            ],
            "lineWidth": 2,
            "tooltip": {
                "valueDecimals": 4
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I remove the `plotOptions.area` property nothing changes in the graph, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Notice that with your current data the error occurs in the console:

https://assets.highcharts.com/errors/15/

2. The `fillColor` feature works only for particular series - like area, pie, funnel, pyramid, arearange etc, so you need to define the type of the series that you want to implemnent.

Simplified demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5r8gxh2b/